# Is it possible to change protected variables from inherited class in java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods, program-entry-point

Ex:

```
class A {
    protected Integer x;

    class A () {
       x = new Integer(0);
    }

    public setX(Integer m) {
       x = m;
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public class B () {
       super();
    }

    public static void main () {
       B b = new B();
       b.setX(69);
       System.out.println("Value of x is: " + b.x);  // expect to be 69. Is it correct?      
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you could have tried it on your own:)

Comment: I bet it took you as long to ask this question as it would have done to try it. Perhaps you had a different result on your local machine? Please don't take that as an attack, you have asked a perfectly valid question :)

Comment: Thank you all. I actually just wanna verify my thoughts because Im in middle of a debugging a big project. Thanks again!

Comment: BTW: I would use an `int` rather than an `Integer` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is what is `protected` for:)

Comment: @tsubasa - Yes, I see no problem with your code:) By the way, we are not a compiler here:)

Answer (score 2):

Protected access means that the member (or method) is visible from within the same package **and** within the class hierarchy.
So yes, your code does have the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

It's not considered a good practice to use protected variables with inheritance.

The right way to do this (without violating encapsulation) is using private accesors for the variables and public (or protected) getters and setters.